# Error when calling submit function (referencing html form)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have looked at previous questions and most of them say that if the form/input name is submit, it will overwrite the function submit but I do not have anything named submit. I am still getting this error.

JS:

```
<div id="reportrange" class="pull-left" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 25%">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
<span></span> <b class="caret"></b> 

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();
    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));

        document.getElementById('tests').value = start;
        document.getElementById('teste').value = end;
        document.getElementById('testing').submit();
    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div> 
    <form  method="post" action= "" id = "testing" >
        <input type="hidden" name="tests" id="tests" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="teste" id="teste" value="">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You're calling `.submit()` on a form element. You need to give the form an id and call submit on the form element.

Comment: @commanderZiltoid thank you! that got rid of that error, but now my page won't stop refreshing (it keeps calling the function)

Comment: Would need to see more of the code. It sounds like the function is being called on page load somewhere causing the submit() to fire off.

Comment: @commanderZiltoid  I have updated the code to show all of the javascript.  The javascript is actually a daterangepicker which is like a calendar and I am trying to get the dates that I choose when clicking on the calendar dates and store them into a php variable that I can use to query with sql. (I am making some sort of statement so I need the dates to filter my query). The cb function updates when a new range is selected, but I guess it keeps updating because my function is getting called non-stop. Please ask if you need more information. Thank you

Comment: You are calling `cb(start, end);` when the page is loaded. This is submitting the form back to the page, which then calls the function again and sticks in an infinite loop.

Comment: @commanderZiltoid thank you so much for all your help, I was able to resolve my issue. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You're off to a great start. Just connect the function to your form like this:

```
<form  method="post" action="" onsubmit="return cb()">
```

That way, when you submit the form, it will run that function. In your function, you can also CANCEL that submit by returning false, like

```
function cb(start, end) {
     return false;
}
```

If you don't return false, or if you return true, you'll submit the form - no need for a submit() call.

Good luck!

Comment: What is `greeting()`?

Comment: Sorry - I changed it - was just a function name - any function will work.